# LaTeXTools on sublime: Please help me find the LaTeXTools.sublime-settings file

Tags: sublime-text

Im desperately trying to find the LaTeXTools.sublime-settings file that I'm supposed to edit in order to use latextools. I'm looking in this file:

/Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/LateXTools

and its not there. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to create the file. Try the menu: Preferences --> Package Settings --> LaTeXTools --> Settings User

Answer (score 1):

*(This answer is to expand the comment from the user DG')*

In a fresh install of ST3, the command `~$ find -iname "*latextools*"` outputs:

```
.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/LaTeXTools/LaTeXTools Preferences.sublime-settings.OLD
.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/LaTeXTools/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings
```

As you can see, the file *LaTexTools.sublime-settings* is already there. **BUT, this is not the one you should edit**

The first lines of that files explains what to do:

> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!! Open the Command Palette and run the "Reconfigure and migrate settings" command. Alternatively, select the "Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings" item from the Preferences, Package Settings, LaTeXTools menu, or open the ST console and type 
> sublime.run_command("latextools_migrate")

This is more or less what the user DG' sugested in his/her comment.

After following those instructions you will have the correct file to edit in:

```
.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings
```

Comment: `find` just gives me "illegal option -i" so we're not off to a good start.

Comment: That command is intended for Linux OS. Which one are you using?

Comment: OS X  (seems to be OP's as well)

Comment: I have no Mac to test, but seems that the `find` command is available as well. Try it without the "i": `find . -name "*latextools*"`

Comment: Did you mean `find . -iname` instead of `find -iname`?

Comment: The dot only specifies the folder where to start the search. In Ubuntu, if omitted, the search starts from the current directory. So you may write `find /home/user/ -name "*latextools*"` that will output the same as the commented command if you are in the user folder. For further info I suggest you to read the documentation about the `find` command in OS X